# How to redirect traffic through IPv6 IPSec (strongswan) gateway?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, ipv6, ipsec, strongswan

I'm trying to set up IPSec secured connection to the gateway. Have three hosts:

```
A:
eth1 - fec0:1::1/64

B:
eth1 - fec0:1::2/64
eth2 - fec0:2::2/64
which is gateway between A and C; forwarding is set to 1 in sysctl

C:
eth1 - fec0:2:3/64
```

I'd like to build IPsec connecten between A and B, which will be insecure forwarded between B and C.

ipsec.conf:

```
config setup
    charondebug="ike 2, knl 2, cfg 1"

ca strongswan
    cacert=ca.crt
    auto=add

conn %default
    ikelifetime=60m
    keylife=20m
    rekeymargin=3m
    keyingtries=1
    mobike=no
    keyexchange=ikev2

conn host-host
    left=fec0:1::1
    leftcert=hostA.crt
    leftid=@hostA
    right=fec0:1::2
    rightid=%any
    type=transport
    auto=add
```

B's configuration looks similiar. I tried to set auto=route, but then I'm not able to initialize any connection.

Using such configuration only traffic addressed to B is secured. When I try to send something from A to C - it is on the whole path insecured.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using such configuration only traffic addressed to B is secured. When I try to send something from A to C - it is on the whole path insecured.

That's exactly how it should be. You established a Transport Mode IPsec SA between A and B, which means there are IPsec policies that only apply for traffic between these two hosts. If you want to secure traffic between A and C (on the path between A and B) you have to use tunnel mode and configure the appropriate traffic selectors/policies.

Either add an additional connection:

```
conn host-c
  also=host-host
  rightsubnet=fec0:2:3/128
  type=tunnel
```

Or change the existing connection:

```
conn host-host # or host-hosts
  left=fec0:1::1
  leftcert=hostA.crt
  leftid=@hostA
  right=fec0:1::2
  rightid=%any
  rightsubnet=fec0:1::2/128,fec0:2:3/128
  type=tunnel
  auto=add
```

The configuration on B has to be changed accordingly.